# jQuery UI Modal Dialog should be fixed on scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any possibility to fix the modal window for jQuery UI, so when the user is using the scroller on the right side, the side behind scrolls, but the modal window is staying fix?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Create a css class with the fixed position:

```
.fixed-dialog{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Then append the class as part of the options when you create the dialog:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog' });
```

Here is a working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3hrSv/
The example is not too flashy because I couldn't get jsfiddle to style the dialog.

If you would like to center the dialog in the middle of the screen try setting `top:50%; left:50%;` in your css as suggested by: http://css-tricks.com/320-quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: Ok, but the layoer will be not centered. It will stay 50px top and 50px left, but this is not center. How to center it?

Comment: Niko Nik I updated my answer to handle the centering, I didn't realize you wanted to keep it centered.

Comment: @jk.  Thanks i didn't realize you could do that with js fiddle.

Comment: using this approach starting with 1.9.0 if you scroll to bottom before clicking on the link that opens the popup the dialog will go offscreen

Comment: I needed to use `position: fixed !important;` as other classes in use were setting it to `absolute` instead

Comment: I know this is an old answer but i came across it and noticed the advice to center the modal which is wrong. Setting a top and left position of 50% will give you a modal in the bottom right of the screen as the top left of the modal will be centered not the center of the modal. JqueryUi already has javascript can center the modal by doing `$('.selector').dialog({ position: 'center' }); ` so all you need is `position: fixed;` in your css.

Comment: The `dialogClass` option has been deprecated in favor of the `classes` option, using the `ui-dialog` property. [link](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass). The updated code in this case would be `$( ".selector" ).dialog(classes: { 'ui-dialog': 'fixed-dialog' });`.

Answer (score 11):

If you want all of your dialogs to have this behavior, you can modify your `jquery.ui.dialog.css` file.

Change:

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

To:

```
.ui-dialog { position: fixed; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

or, if you want to preserve the original file, just add the line:

```
div.ui-dialog {position:fixed;}
```

to one of your css files referenced by the page, or the style block on the page.

Answer (score 4):

Or to apply the CSS when you create it:

```
        $("#Modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 'auto',
        position: [50, 150],
        create: function (event) {
            $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'fixed', "left": 50, "top": 150 });
          }
        });
```

Comment: Perfect for what I needed! Also, you don't need to specify the exact position either, if you don't want to. It's compatible with the `draggable: true` proprerty so you can let the user move it and it will stay where they left it as they scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found that James' answer (to revise JQuery's div.ui-dialog to position:fixed) provided one-half of the answer to this question. The other half is this: Be sure that the height of the parent element is 100%. In my case, the body is the parent to my dialogs, so I have this line:

```
<body style='height: 100%; min-height: 100%;'>
```

That, plus James' suggestion to add this to my CSS file:

```
div.ui-dialog {position:fixed;}
```

... finally got my dialogs to appear at the center of the browser window and stay there while I scroll. Hope this helps future googlers who may pass through here.